# How to encode data on a JSON file in swift

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

In my swift app I'm trying to encode data on a local txt file, this is my code:

```
   func encodeData(data: String) {

    let file = "myfile.txt"

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            print(fileURL)
        }
        catch {print(error.localizedDescription)}
    }
}
```

This is the path:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9C39138-27D4-4D6A-8D92-118315E01A9C/Documents/myfile.txt

But how can I find my txt file named myfile.txt ?

Comment: What do you mean by "find" the text file?

Comment: You wrote `myfile.txt` to the Documents folder. So read it from there as well.